# sql server - "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which inserts / copies data from `table2` to `table1`,   does anybody have any idea on how i can work around the following errors.

initially this was the code (omitted other columns), which results to `"cannot insert duplicate key in object [TABLE1]"` which i found out later that `ROW_NUMBER` gets only one row

modified it to get a sequence of rows:

`(SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 8) + LEFT((SELECT CAST (MAX(Code) AS int), RN = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TABLE2].[U_PosNo])) FROM [TABLE1]), 8),8)),`

now I'm getting `"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub query is not introduced with EXISTS."`

```
 INSERT INTO [TABLE1] 
  (  
 Code,  
 Name,  
 U_ProdNo,
 ....
'''
 )

 (SELECT 
    (SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 8) + LEFT((SELECT CAST (MAX(Code) AS int) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TABLE2].[U_PosNo]) FROM [TABLE1]), 8),8)), 
    (SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 30) + LEFT((SELECT CAST (MAX(Name) AS int) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TABLE2].[U_PosNo]) FROM [TABLE1]), 30),30)), 
...
''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the subquery only to get the max value for table1 and start the row number with that value, but, you are including your other values inside... Correlated subqueries must return a single value.

```
INSERT Table1 (...)
SELECT 
    RN = (SELECT MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)) FROM Table1) /* Subquery that returns single value */ 
             + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [U_PosNo]) /* your row number */
        , /*Other columns*/ ....
FROM Table2
```

To get the formatted code for your approach

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(
        REPLICATE('0', 8) 
        + CAST(
            (SELECT MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)) FROM Table1) 
            + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_PosNo) 
        AS VARCHAR)
        , 8)
FROM Table2
```

For the other subqueries I recommend you to join or apply table 3 since you are using the same condition for all of them....

Use join if you need to insert one record per row in Table3, Left if you want to insert even if there is no records there.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(
        REPLICATE('0', 8) 
        + CAST(
            (SELECT MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)) FROM Table1) 
            + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_PosNo) 
        AS VARCHAR)
        , 8),
    Table3.LPrice, 
    CASE 
        WHEN [Table2].[MaInC] = 1 THEN [Table2].[MatIdColumn] 
        ELSE [TABLE3].[Column2] END
FROM Table2 
/*LEFT*/ JOIN Table3 ON [TABLE3].[ItemCode] = [Table2].[U_ItmNo]
```

If you need to use only one matching record from Table3, let's say the last one, use APPLY, CROSS if you want only records with Table3, OUTER if you want them even without it.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(
        REPLICATE('0', 8) 
        + CAST(
            (SELECT MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)) FROM Table1) 
            + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_PosNo) 
        AS VARCHAR)
        , 8),
    T3.LPrice, 
    CASE 
        WHEN [Table2].[MaInC] = 1 THEN [Table2].[MatIdColumn] 
        ELSE [T3].[Column2] END
FROM Table2 
CROSS /*OUTER*/ APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table3 
    WHERE [TABLE3].[ItemCode] = [Table2].[U_ItmNo]
    ORDER BY DateField DESC
) T3
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, now I'm get this error: **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Comment: I have basically implemented what you shared for those 2 columns did not change anything, can it be an issue with the duplicate data from the [Table2].[U_PosNo]?

Comment: The error must be in a different part of your query, is there another place where you are using subqueries??

Comment: apart from a couple of Scalar functions, there's this one                     `(SELECT [TABLE3].[LPrice] 
    FROM  [TABLE3] 
       WHERE  [TABLE3].[ItemCode] = [Table2].[ItmNo] ) , 
   CASE WHEN [Table2].[MaInC] = 1  
      THEN [Table2].[MatIdColumn] 
    ELSE (SELECT [TABLE3].[Column2] 
            FROM [TABLE3]
           WHERE [TABLE3].[ItemCode] = [Table2].[U_ItmNo]) 
  END , `

Comment: the relation between table 2 and table 3 is 1 to 1??

Comment: Depending of what do you need I would add table 3 as a join or apply, is not the best idea to have 3 subqueries to the same table with the same condition

Comment: 1 to many. there's a scalar function that i called in the query..commented it out and it executed perfectly with the corresponding column in the insert block  as well, I hope that's not the cause

Comment: Sorry to inform you that it is the cause, the query in your scalar function is returning more than 1 value, and if the relation is 1 to N, they are subject to throw the same error in the future

Comment: the issue: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. comes from the 2 subqueries    I initially had a problem with

Comment: If the relation between table 2 and table 3 is 1 to N, then you need to define what do you want to do with duplicated records... If you want to insert one record per record found in table3, then use a join (left if the relation can be 0) if you need only one record then define which one of them you want to use and use apply

Comment: What about using distinct on Table2, because that's where the duplicated data is?

Comment: Your subqueries are returning more than one record, you need to fix the subqueries, not the external query

Comment: ` SELECT 
    RIGHT(
        REPLICATE('0', 8) 
        + CAST(
            (SELECT MAX(CAST(Code AS INT)) FROM Table1) 
            + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_PosNo) 
        AS VARCHAR)
        , 8)
FROM Table2 ` I mean here, because table2 has duplicate values in it

Comment: You cannot get a duplicated record using row_count(), check the update

Comment: If you use SELECT TOP 1 in your sub-queries will also work, but is better to add an ORDER BY clause too to ensure that you get the desired value

Comment: I out commented the other sub-queries plus the scalar functions, still the same error of more than 1 value, plus i did apply your recent update, nothing still

Comment: Seeing your first approach...Are you wrapping this query into parenthesis? don't do that

Comment: yes i did, but i removed it, and nothing changed, any other approach i could take?

Comment: I really need to see the whole query to find the isssue

Comment: If you can’t share it here for privacy send me a DM on Twitter

Comment: you can find me as @dbrughera

Comment: Done, please follow back, so that I can send you the query via DM

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the inner SELECT queries are fine, it might just work if you remove the parentheses around the outer SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE1] 
(  
    Code,  
    Name,  
    U_ProdNo,
    ....
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 8) + LEFT((SELECT CAST (MAX(Code) AS int) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TABLE2].[U_PosNo]) FROM [TABLE1]), 8),8)), 
    (SELECT RIGHT (REPLICATE('0', 30) + LEFT((SELECT CAST (MAX(Name) AS int) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TABLE2].[U_PosNo]) FROM [TABLE1]), 30),30)), 
    ...
```